# WP Locations Order Ascending

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I am trying to sort order locations in Word Press, the locations are stored within the posts meta data.

on my home page is a drop down box for location that users may select i would like them to be ordered from A -Z

```
    <?php

                                                $args_location = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
                                                $lastposts = get_posts( $args_location );

                                                $all_post_location = array();
                                                foreach( $lastposts as $post ) {
                                                    $all_post_location[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_location', true );
                                                }

                                                $directors = array_unique($all_post_location);
                                                asort($directors);
                                                foreach ($directors as $director) { ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $director; ?>"><?php echo $director; ?></option>
                                                <?php }
```

any help would be much appreciated

I did try to do this to sort the order

```
    <?php

                                                $args_location = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
                                                $lastposts = get_posts( $args_location );

                                                $all_post_location = array();
                                                foreach( $lastposts as $post ) {
                                                    $all_post_location[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_location', true );
                                                }

                                                $directors = array_unique($all_post_location);
                                                asort($directors);
                                                **sort($directors);**
                                                foreach ($directors as $director) { ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $director; ?>"><?php echo $director; ?></option>
                                                <?php }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually get them in one step, as get_posts just uses WP_Query. This:

```
 $args_location = array(
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'orderby' => 'meta_value',
     'meta_key' => 'post_location',
     'order' => 'ASC'
 );
 $lastposts = get_posts( $args_location );
```

Your posts will then be sorted by post_location.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that was very helpful i am learning PHP slowly, i did only have to change one thing with your answer you added a . instead of a , after 'meta_key' => 'post_location'.